# How to find LC?

Tags: geometry, quadrilateral

$ADCB$ is a quadrilateral. Let $M,K,N,L$ on $BA,AD,DC,CB$ respectively such that $MKNL$ is the parallelogram and $M,N$ is the mid-point of $BA,DC$ respectively. If $AK=8$, $KD=10$ and $LB=11$. Find $LC$

[image: Here is the photo]

I extended $BC$ meet $D$ at $E$ so $ADEB$ is isosceles trapezoid ( Do I even allowed to do that!? ). I draw parallel line of $BC$ cut $N$ meet $DE$ and $DL$ at $F,G$ respectively so $F,G$ is the mid-point of $DE$ and $DL$? ( Am I not allowed to do that? ) And then $C$ is the mid-point of $LE$ so $LC=(10+8-11)/2=7/2$. Please help me I don't even know if I'm right or wrong at all. And I'd appreciate it if you could provide me another solution

Comment: Re-organize your question so that it corresponds with the picture drawn.

Comment: @Mick hi again Mick. What should I do? That's all my idea but I also don't think my idea correct at all

Comment: In the picture, I find quad. ABCD but in the question I find ADLB.

Comment: @Mick oops sorry I change it back

Comment: @Mick the actual problem is not English so I just look at the picture and write it down. Sorry that I make it more confusing hahaha